# MFC CScrollView does not clear background

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

My English is not perfect. I am using Visual C++ 2019 and MFC. Example program: an SDI program, the base of the view is `CScrollView`, draws 128*128 0s in a matrix. But MFC does not clear the background at scrolling with the scrollbar. Have you an idea? Thank you.

In settings of Windows, I am using 96 dpi * 3 = 288 dpi.
I tried: 96 dpi mode is affected so.

How can I upload the example program to this?

```
void CsdView::OnDraw(CDC *pDC) {
    CsdDoc *pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if  (!pDoc)
        return;
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, 0xFFFFFF);
    CPoint  pos = GetDeviceScrollPosition();
    TRACE(L"OnDraw: %4u.%4u - %4u.%4u, %4u.%4u\n", rect.right, rect.bottom, pos.x, pos.y, rect.right + pos.x, rect.bottom+pos.y);
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++ i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; ++ j)
            pDC->TextOutW(j*20 - pos.x, i*54 - pos.y, L"0", 1);
}

void CsdView::OnInitialUpdate() {
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();
    CSize sizeTotal;
    sizeTotal.cx = 20*128;
    sizeTotal.cy = 54*128;
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, sizeTotal);
}

BOOL CsdView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC *pDC) {
    CBrush  brush(0xFFFFFF);
    FillOutsideRect(pDC, &brush);
    return  TRUE;
//  return CScrollView::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}
```

I can not upload picture and code as a comment, so I must edit the original question.

[image]

A little bug is remained. The orginal code (MDI MFC):

```
void CIDEView::OnDraw(CDC *pDC) {
    CIDEDoc *const d = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(d);
    if  (! d)
        return;
    CPoint  const pos = GetDeviceScrollPosition();
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    OffsetRect(&rect, pos.x, pos.y);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, bkcolor);
    auto    oldfont = pDC->SelectObject(&font);
    pDC->SetBkColor(bkcolor);
    pDC->SetTextColor(textcolor);
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    const int   cxs = pos.x / mincw, cys = pos.y / lineheight;
    const int   cxe = (rect.right + mincw-1) / mincw,
                cye = (rect.bottom + 41) / lineheight;
    for (int i = cys; i <= cye; ++ i)
        for (int j = cxs; j <= cxe; ++ j)
            pDC->TextOutW(textmargin+j*mincw, i*lineheight, L"0", 1);
    pDC->SelectObject(oldfont);
}

void CIDEView::OnInitialUpdate() {
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, {linewidth, 128*lineheight});
}

BOOL CIDEView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC *pDC) {
    return  TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Pls add the C++ tag to your question for proper syntax highlighting.

Comment: The error was in my code: for cxe/cxs, -4 is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CScrollView` class is a view with scrolling capabilities. You use it almost like a `CView` (ie drawing in the `OnDraw()` member), only you have to take into account the possible scrolling.

The `GetClientRect()` function returns the visible client area, and the coordinates returned are not relative to the view origin, but to the window origin, ie the `left` and `top` members are always 0. The `CDC` parameter in the `OnDraw()` function though are relative to the logical view origin, so an adjustment is needed.

As for your code, you don't need to use the `OnEraseBkgnd()` function, because you do so in `OnDraw()`. You fill only the visible part of the window, but that's very much OK. So it would best to remove it. Also, the coordinates passed to the `TextOutW()` function must be relative to the view origin, so the `-pos.x` and `-pos.y` adjustments are wrong. Instead, it's the rectanlge passed to the `FillSolidRect()` function that needs to be adjusted. So, your code would become:

```
void CsdView::OnDraw(CDC *pDC)
{
    CsdDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    CPoint  pos = GetScrollPosition();
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    // Adjust client rect to device coordinates
    OffsetRect(&rect, pos.x, pos.y);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, 0xFFFFFF);
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 128; ++j)
            pDC->TextOutW(j * 20, i * 54, L"0", 1);
}
```

However this code is "wasteful", as it paints the whole view. It can be optimized to paint only the visible part. It will draw only the 0s for which even one pixel lies in the visible part (didn't `#define` anything, just used your hard-coded 20 and 54 values). Also changed the color to yellow, so you can test it better (white is the default background color).

```
void CsdView::OnDraw(CDC *pDC)
{
    CsdDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    CPoint  pos = GetScrollPosition();
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    // Adjust client rect to device coordinates
    OffsetRect(&rect, pos.x, pos.y);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, 0x00FFFF);
    // Paint only the items in the visible part
    int xL = rect.left / 20,
        xR = (rect.right + 19) / 20,
        yT = rect.top / 54,
        yB = (rect.bottom + 53) / 54;
    for (int i = yT; i < yB; ++i)
        for (int j = xL; j < xR; ++j)
            pDC->TextOutW(j * 20, i * 54, L"0", 1);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

In the revised code, why are the doc, pos, cxs etc variables `const`? There are also quite a few bugs in your logic:

- You set your view size in `OnInitialUpdate()`, rather assuming that `linewidth` equals to `textmargin + 128*mincw`. If not, revise your code again.
- The `rect` is already adjusted (using `OffsetRect()`), so it is wrong to add `pos.x` again.
- Since you have the cell sizes in variables, don't use hard-coded numbers. For example the code for `cxe` should become `cxe = (rect.right + mincw - 1) / mincw`; Update the `cye` code similarly.
- Also you paint at an offset of `textmargin`. The code should then become `cxe = (rect.right - textmargin + mincw - 1) / mincw`;
- The code I posted works OK with the `<` condition in the loops, you don't need `<=`. Do the math and you will find that this is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you. This is a short example, originally I wrote only the visible part, there was no FillOutsideRect, and 20/54 was not fixed. I am using high DPI 96 dpi * 3 = 288 dpi: 0.16 mm * 3 = 0.48 mm, 0,6 viewing distance from my eyes. At now this is by far better, but a some bug remained: I can not upload a picture to this, so I will try it in an another answer.

Comment: I edited my original question (for showing a picture about the remained small bug).

Comment: The error was in my code: for cxs/cxe, - 4 is required.

Comment: -4? Where exactly?

Comment: My original code was (parts):

In the cycle: pDC->TextOutW(textmargin + j * mincw, i * lineheight, L"0", 1);

So, started with textmargin. Other parts:

  const int cxs = pos.x / mincw, cys = pos.y / lineheight;
  const int cxe = (rect.right + mincw-1) / mincw,

At cxs, cxe, must be: pos. x - textmargin instead of pos.x, rect.right - textmargin instead of rect.right. I computed the visible area: I drawn only the visible area.